# Tourist visa, teaching English in Spain?

Tags: legal, schengen-visas, work

Is it legal for someone on a tourist visa to earn cash by giving English tuition (1 on 1 or private academies)?

I know there's a hefty freelancer registration system in place, but I've been told that teaching state-mandated subjects like English is exempted from taxation.

Comment: As for all visa questions, the country is needed. Do not edit it out of the question, as what was left had no meaning (but the answers still show which country you tried to hide.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tax and registration requirements and visa regulations are two separate issues. Any type of work, which this is, is most definitely illegal on a Schengen short-stay visa or visa-free stay without a separate authorization.

Comment: +1, but please add the part about detection and consequences

Comment: @GayotFow The likelihood (and its consequences)  is similar in nature to winning at [Russian roulette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_roulette). Statistical data no doubt exists, but cannot be relied on to predict future events.